# cannot add textContent to more than one elements in NodeList

Tags: javascript

I have 2 elements with 'copyright' class and wanted to change their textContent but it shows me an error: Uncaught TypeError: can't assign to property "textContent" on 2: not an object

```
const copyright = document.querySelectorAll('.copyright')
for (let i in copyright) {
    copyright[i].textContent = new Date().getFullYear()
}
```

I tried to use innerHTML but it didn't change much

Comment: It's working fine in my side

Comment: In here `for (let i in copyright)` the variable `i` is not an index, but the element itself. so inside the loop `i.textContent = 'foo'` should suffice

Comment: @Jhilton It's not,you can test the code by youself and it will works fine

Comment: [Don't use `for…in` enumerations on array-like objects!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)

Comment: @Jhilton No. It's not `for … of`

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] please, ideally [as a StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/1048572), that demonstrates the problem and throws that error?

Comment: SUGGESTION: Add `console.log('i:' + i + ', copyright[i]: ' + copyright[i]);` to your loop -*BEFORE* your assignment - and see what happens under Chrome Developer Tools (or equivalent).  I suspect one of the elements in your HTML isn't what you expect it to be...

Comment: @paulsm4 Better: `console.log({ i, "copyright[i]": copyright[i] });`. Avoid coercing everything to strings. Alternatively, use a debugger.

Comment: @lucumt try in "strict mode" you'll get the same error as OP.

Comment: Now the question is "Why did they make these properties enumerable?"...

Comment: To myself: There was https://github.com/whatwg/webidl/issues/738

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `forEach`, `for ... of`, or an usual `for` loop instead. With these you can access every element in the `NodeList`. Because `NodeList` is not a normal `Array`, using `for...in` on it will give you other properties of the `NodeList` object, like `"item"`, `"keys"`, and the problematic one in your case, `.length`. Indeed, in "strict mode", you can't set properties on number primitives.

Using `forEach` that would give:

```js
const copyright = document.querySelectorAll('.copyright');
copyright.forEach(elem => {
    elem.textContent = new Date().getFullYear();
})
```

Using `for...of`:

```js
const copyright = document.querySelectorAll('.copyright');
for(const elem of copyright) {
    elem.textContent = new Date().getFullYear();
}
```

And using the usual `for` loop:

```js
const copyright = document.querySelectorAll('.copyright');
for(let i = 0; i < copyright.length; i++) {
    copyright[i].textContent = new Date().getFullYear();
}
```